# EWW cannot access HTTPS sites via proxy

Tags: eww, url

Here's my proxy setup:

```el
(setq url-proxy-services '(("no_proxy" . "my-corp-proxy")
                           ("http" . "my-corp-proxy:8080")
                           ("https" . "my-port-proxy:8080")))
```

I can use `eww` to access HTTP sites, but when I try to access HTTPS sites I get this response:

[image]

I've installed `gnutls` as well; evaluating `(gnutls-available-p)` gives `t`.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you access HTTPS sites with curl? `$ http_proxy=my-port-proxy:8080 curl https://www.example.com`

Comment: Yes, I can access HTTPS sites with curl behind the same proxy.

Comment: Can you access HTTPS sites without the proxy?

Comment: @feklee no. Im inside corporate network, no direct internet connection.

Comment: If you remove configuration of `url-proxy-services`, do you get the same error message? Can you access the web from IE? I’m asking because maybe you have to set up the proxy using Windows settings.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I have finally got it working.

I applied the patch in https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11788#52.

Then, to solve

> error in process filter: url-http-generic-filter: Wrong type argument:
>   number-or-marker-p, http/1.1

I just had to add a line to `url-http.el:462` which was

```
(skip-chars-forward "HTTP/")        ; Skip HTTP Version
(skip-chars-forward "http/")        ; Skip HTTP Version
```

Comment: FWIW, the fix is included in Emacs 26.

Comment: Also, the first argument to `skip-chars-forward` is interpreted as an unquoted regexp character set, not literally.