# Emacs failing to access HTTPS URL behind a proxy

Tags: eww, proxy

I hoped that [this problem](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/19161/30120)'s solution would solve it for me, but it didn't.  I've got my proxy set up as follows (slightly redacted):

```
(setq url-proxy-services
       '(("no_proxy" . "^\\(localhost\\|10.*\\)")
         ("http" . "proxy.xxx.com:8080")
         ("https" . "proxy.xxx.com:8080")))
```

and when I use `eww` to make a request I get (again, slightly redacted):

```
Request Error: https://www.google.co.uk/
XXX Dynamic IT

         Request Error (invalid_request)

      Proxy: xxx-xx-20

      Url: https://www.google.co.uk/
      Time: [11/09/2020:08:46:35 GMT]
      Client: xxx.xxx.8.32
     Your request for https://www.google.co.uk/ could not be processed. Request
     could not be handled
     This could be caused by a misconfiguration, or possibly a malformed
     request.
```

I was wondering if this could be because it's trying to talk HTTPS to the proxy.  I tried following the example on [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UrlPackage#toc6) where the protocol is included in the proxy specification, so I'd instead have:

```
(setq url-proxy-services
       '(("no_proxy" . "^\\(localhost\\|10.*\\)")
         ("http" . "http://proxy.xxx.com:8080")
         ("https" . "http://proxy.xxx.com:8080")))
```

but this doesn't work either.  I get a couple of lines in the `*Messages*` buffer that suggest I shouldn't be doing it that way:

```
Contacting host: http:80
open-network-stream: http/80 Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Am I doing something wrong and/or daft?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's your Emacs version? Does this only happen when accessing https resources?

Comment: Good questions!  It's v25.2.2 and yes, only with HTTPS resources (HTTP works fine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely related to the following bug which was fixed in Emacs 26.1: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=11788.

Comment: Thanks, updating to v27.1 (that's what was available as a snap on Ubuntu 18.04) does seem to fix `eww` not being able to access HTTPS resources.  Unfortunately, trying to use the [Lazy Installer](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get#the-lazy-installer) for `el-get` still fails, but I don't think this is related so I'll treat that as a separate problem and mark your answer as the solution.  Thanks again!